# Javascript redirect and Pass Argument to redirected Page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a main page that contains two buttons. Each of the buttons should redirect to the same page, however, the page that you are redirected to should do different things depending on the button you pressed. How can I redirect the user to that new page and pass in an argument depending on which button you have clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross-browser event handling is much simpler with a toolkit like JQuery:

HTML:

```
<button data-param="foo">Foo</button>
<button data-param="bar">Bar</button>
```

JQuery code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    window.location = window.location.href + '?param=' + $(this).data('param');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6DK5J/

Comment: How can I then pick it up at the javascript that is that connects to the second page I am redirecting to ?  say I an in page.html?p=1 , what is the function that I can use to get p? is it this.data ?

Comment: You'll need a function to extract the URL parameters, there's [one here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by 'pass in an argument' but if you mean by URL query string then you can simply set up a form with an action to the page in question with a `GET` method:

```
<form action="page.html" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit1" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit2" />
</form>
```

The redirected URL will be `page.html?submit1=Submit1` if the first button is clicked and `page.html?submit2=Submit2` if the second button is clicked.

Comment: does the GET here work even when you are offline, i.e the page should be purely javascript and should work offline ? and can you add how in javascript I can pick up the querystring please.? THANKS

Comment: As long as `page.html` exists it will work, there's no server-side operation involved

Comment: One more thing, I have the buttons already made as <a href> links, is that still possible?

Comment: Not using that method, no, only values from `<input>` elements would be included in the query string. Are you able to change the links to `<input>` elements?