# add an class to a function goForit()

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function goForit() {
  var passwd;
  passwd = document.forms['giftForm'].pass.value;
  if(passwd=="yes"){
  window.open ('eat.html','_self',false)
  }
  else{
  alert('Password wrong');
  }
}

<form id="giftForm">        
    <input type="text" id="pass" placeholder="" style="font-size:150%;"/>
    <br />
    <input type="button" onClick="goForit()" value="Submit" style="font-size:100%; margin-top:15px;" />                 
 </form>
```

If someone enters "yes" as the password and clicks the submit button.  The user will be redirected to the eat.html page.

I want to pass the .carrot class with the redirect, so the proper image will appear.  How do I add the .carrot class to the following code?

Comment: If you are using PHP as well, you can pass it with GET. Not sure if it is possible with just javascript.

Comment: Oh God, please tell me this is not how you are authenticating users.

Comment: @xbonez don't even bring that up...i would die hahah.

Comment: @xbonez this is nothing that will ever see production.  Its only use will be for a 5 minute presentation, then all will be scratched.

Comment: @EliteGamer on the redirect, could I do something like body class="carrot" to get it to trigger on load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

[How to redirect on another page and pass parameter in url from table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100563/how-to-redirect-on-another-page-and-pass-parameter-in-url-from-table)

Html:

```
<input type="button" name="theButton" value="Detail" class="btn" data-username="{{result['username']}}" />
```

then check the redirected url's Location:

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', (function() {

    var name = $(this).data('username');

    if (name != undefined || name != null) {
        window.location = '/player_detail?username=' + name;
    }
});​
```

Also, another StackOverflow Question:

[Javascript redirect and Pass Argument to redirected Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774731/javascript-redirect-and-pass-argument-to-redirected-page)

Comment: @tymeJV ha, sorry, let me re-write in Javascript

Comment: Thought I'd let ya know before a hail of downvotes came flying in :D

Comment: Since `undefined == null`, the second expression is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You've accepted an answer, but here's an alternative that's closer to the original and doesn't need jQuery:

```
<button type="button" value="goForit(this)" value="carrot" ... >Go for it</button>
```

Then in the function:

```
function gotForit(el) {
  if (el.form.pass.value.toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
    window.location = 'eat.html?username=' + el.value;
  } else {
    alert('oops…');
  }
}
```